# Tweenlite - a sequence chain of TweenLite.to not triggering

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, tween, gsap

Its pretty simple what im trying to achieve.
I have a MC on Stage, which im trying to tween to different X coordinates.

I've set up four TweenLite.to sequences, however for some weird reason only one is being triggered - what am I doing wrong?

```
TweenLite.to(slider.mc_slider,1,{x:_returnXPos(95), ease:menuEasing});
TweenLite.to(slider.mc_slider,1,{delay: 1, x:_returnXPos(35), ease:menuEasing});
TweenLite.to(slider.mc_slider,1,{delay: 2, x:_returnXPos(50), ease:menuEasing});

//Function which returns x coordinate of Sliderbar - related to defined percentage
function _returnXPos(definedPercentage:Number):Number {
    var defineWidth:Number = slider.mc_background.width * (definedPercentage/100);
    return defineWidth;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem might be that you have to make sure that you're using the `OverwriteManager` with the right settings, otherwise it might just overwrite your tweens, regardless of the delays, see: http://www.greensock.com/overwritemanager/

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what dain suggested, you might also want to check out [TimelineLight](http://www.greensock.com/timelinelite/).

Comment: Thanks gencha, I will surely look into that - wasnt aware that greensock had so many things available.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code (not at a machine I can test this on) only the last tween is running. If you want them running in sequence you need to specify a call-back function. Unfortunately you cannot use anonymous functions.

```
TweenLite.to(slider.mc_slider,1,{x:_returnXPos(95),ease:menuEasing,onComplete:nextTween,onCompleteParams:[35]});

function nextTween(newPos:int)
{
    TweenLite.to(slider.mc_slider,1,{x:_returnXPos(newPos),ease:menuEasing,onComplete:finalTween,onCompleteParams:[50]});
}

function finalTween(newPos:int)
{
    TweenLite.to(slider.mc_slider,1,{x:_returnXPos(newPos),ease:menuEasing,onComplete:finalTween,onCompleteParams:[50]});
}
```

Not the best answer as you are repeating code THREE times. When I get to a pc I can test this on I'll refactor the code into a single function.

Comment: Hey Dickie, thanks for the answer. I was also thinking about the onComplete function, but just seemed annoying having to do that. Luckely the OverwriteManager did the trick for me - http://www.greensock.com/overwritemanager/ . Thanks for contributing